Using a flag function to validate form fields not working


let flags = false
let newTrackerName = document.querySelector(".newTrackerName")
let newTrackerDate = document.querySelector(".newTrackerDate")
let createTracker = document.querySelector(".createTracker")
let trackerTypeOptions = document.querySelectorAll(".trackerTypeOptions")


createTracker.onclick = () => {

  checkFields(flags)


  if (flags === false) {
    console.log(newTrackerName.value, newTrackerDate.value);
  }
}

const checkFields = flags => {
  if (newTrackerName.value === "") {
    prompts(newTrackerName.getAttribute("title"), "cannot be blank.")
    return flags = true
  }
}

const prompts = (title, message) => {
  console.log(`${title} ${message}`)
}
<div class="newTrackerForm mt-10 flex flex-col gap-y-8 font-bold">
  <div class="uppercase text-xs flex flex-col gap-y-2 text-slate-200">
    <span class="tracking-widest">Name:</span>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="newTrackerName rounded-lg px-2 py-3 text-xs bg-slate-800 uppercase" title="Tracker Name" />
  </div>
  <div class="uppercase text-xs flex flex-col gap-y-2 text-slate-200">
    <span class="tracking-widest">Start Date:</span>
    <input type="date" name="" id="" class="newTrackerDate rounded-lg px-2 py-3 text-xs bg-slate-800" title="Tracker Start Date" />
  </div>
  <div class="uppercase text-xs flex flex-col gap-y-2 text-slate-200">
    <span class="tracking-widest">Type:</span>
    <div class="flex items-center gap-x-2 tracking-widest">
      <input type="radio" name="trackerTypes" id="" class="trackerTypeOptions" value="yesNo" /> Yes/No
      <input type="radio" name="trackerTypes" id="" class="trackerTypeOptions" value="counts" /> Counts
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<button class="createTracker bg-emerald-600 p-3 rounded-lg text-slate-300 font-bold uppercase tracking-widest">Create</button>

</div>



I have a form which is validating user's inputs.
I created a function that checks for empty fields and other checks. I have created a flag variable which returns true if a field is empty and the form will store the data.
However, when I click on the create button , the error prompt is shown with the correct message BUT it also shows the data from other fields. Ideally, it should only show data from all the fields if the flag variable returns false.
let flags = false

createTracker.onclick = () => {

    checkFields(flags) 

    if (flags === false) {
        console.log(document.querySelector("input[name='trackerTypes']:checked").value, newTrackerName.value, newTrackerDate.value, 
minCountRange.value, maxCountRange.value, tagValue);
    }
}

const checkFields = flags =>  {
    if(newTrackerName.value === "") {
        prompts(newTrackerName.getAttribute("title"), "cannot be blank.")
        return flags = true
    }
}

let errors = document.querySelector(".errors")
let closeErrorWindow = document.querySelector(".closeErrorWindow")

let errorMessage = document.querySelector(".errorMessage")
const prompts =  (title, message) => {
    errors.classList.remove("-right-[2000px]")
    errors.classList.add("right-0")
    errorMessage.innerHTML = `${title} ${message}` 
}


I have added all the checks in the checkFields function so I can easily manage if I add new fields or want to add more checks to a particular field.
Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong here?

Please click [edit] and then the button marked [<>] to provide a [mcve]

added the snippet.

It seems it is not clear what should set the global var flag and why you pass it.
flags = checkFields() and const checkFields = () =>  { seems like they may work like you want

I use the flags variable as a reference to check if flag is false. Data from the fields should not be visible if flag returns true.

I meant, your code is not clear on why sets it. My suggestions will clear that up.

You are expecting flags to be modified in checkFields() function. However, the function parameter flags creates a local instance of the variable, which then modifies the value of the local instance.
Come to think of it, flags is already a global variable. You don't have to pass it to any function. You should be able to check its value and modify it in any function (which is dangerous).
So there are two things you can do:

Stop passing the global variable around.

let flags = false;

const checkFields = () =>  {
    if(newTrackerName.value === "") {
        prompts(newTrackerName.getAttribute("title"), "cannot be blank.")
        return flags = true
    }
}


OR

don't create a global variable

const checkFields = () =>  {
  return newTrackerName.value === ""
}

...

const flag = checkFields();

if (flag) {
  prompt(newTrackerName.getAttribute("title"), "cannot be blank.")
}

if (flag === false) {
  ...
}


So, I should not declare the flags variable globally?

Global variables are usually not a good idea, unless it is absolutely necessary. I have modified the option #2 above to show how you can ditch the global variable. Hope that helps. Please accept the answer if this helped you out.

Ok, but if you'll look at the code, the checkFields function is triggered when the create button is clicked and field values are only displayed if flags returns false, I tried by making the flag var local, but I get a reference error when I check it with the click event.
